# ¿Cómo hacer una consulta a mongoatlas desde nodejs?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, sql, mongod

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a una base de datos cloud que cree en mongo atlas, la consulta funciona muy bien si pongo un console.log en la función Aux, pero lo que yo quiero hacer es llamar la función aux que en teoría debería de retornarme un json con la siguiente información: Status,message,method y data, el campo data hace referencia a los datos obtenidos por la consulta de la función GetUsers, esa información que se retorna desde aux se llama desde otro componente. Al momento de yo poner en ejecución el servidor y hacer la llamada al endpoint en postman lo único que me retorna es esto {}, en ves de traerme la información que retorné desde la función aux.

```
const client=require("../db/configdb");
const responseMessage=require("../responses/response");
class UserService{
    CreateUser(data){
        new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            client.connect().then(cli=>{
                const collection = client.db("Database-Reme").collection("users");
                collection.insertOne(data,(insertError,insertResponse)=>{
                    if (insertError) reject(insertError);
                    resolve(insertResponse);
                });
            }).catch(err=>{
                return responseMessage.RequestAlert(400,"No se ha podido insertar","POST");
            });
        });
        return responseMessage.RequestAlert(200,"Se ha insertado correctamente","POST");
        
    }

     GetUsers(){
           return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            client.connect().then(cli=>{
                const collection=client.db("Database-Reme").collection("users");
                collection.find({}).toArray(function(err,result){
                    if (err) reject(err);
                    resolve(result);
                });
            }).catch(err=>{
                return responseMessage.RequestAlert(400,"No se ha podido generar la consulta","GET");
            })
        })
    }
    async Aux(){
        const info=await this.GetUsers();
        const message=responseMessage.RequestData(200,"Consulta exitosa","GET",info);
        console.log(typeof(message));
        return message;
    }
}
module.exports=new UserService();
```

Comment: ¿ Cual es el problema del código que muestras ? ¿ No funciona y obtienes algún error ? ¿ Funciona y los resultados obtenidos no son los esperados ? Por favor, consulta [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Brother, mil disculpas, acabé de re leer la pregunta y me di cuenta que no fui nada claro, la vuelvo a editar